# How to distinguish exponent and ordinary number

Tags: python, digit

The following two expressions return `True`

```
'2'.isdigit()
chr(178).isdigit()
```

the later is exponent.

I am looking for a way to distinguish them for all numbers

Comment: Erm... `'0' <= c <= '9'`?

Comment: ... provided that `c` is just a single character. Of course, you can use `all(...)` for longer strings.

Comment: That's actually an interesting question. I always thought that every `isdigit` number could be converted to `int`, but this can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

> **str.isdigit()**
>
> Return true if all characters in the string are digits
>   and there is at least one character, false otherwise. **Digits include
>   decimal characters and digits that need special handling, such as the
>   compatibility superscript digits.** This covers digits which cannot be
>   used to form numbers in base 10, like the Kharosthi numbers. Formally,
>   a digit is a character that has the property value Numeric_Type=Digit
>   or Numeric_Type=Decimal.

If you want to check if python is able to parse a string as a number, an idiomatic approach is to use try-except.

```
def is_really_digit(s):
   try:
      int(s)
      return True
   except ValueError:
      return False
```

Comment: Thank you! I wonder if above suggestion `'0' <= c <= '9'` is quicker

Comment: The other suggestion is quicker, but both are executed in a few microseconds, so the difference only matters in very performance critical code.

Comment: “Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.” (Donald Knuth)

Comment: Thank you, I have seen this quote before, but forgot who said it. I totally agree with it.